# What is the most appropriate journal for publishing a paper about data collection with QGIS and mobile equipment?

Tags: qgis, mobile, references

I am a QGIS user, and a few months ago, we used QGIS on a PC Tablet to collect data on nesting birds on a cliff directly on the field. The principle is to have QGIS installed on a PC-Tablet with an SQL database, and with easy way to write data.

We are still work on it, and to share this example and cite this work, we would like to write a manuscript, but we don't know in which journal.

Does someone have advice as to which journal we could submit this kind of work?

Answer (score 9):

I'd recommend deciding first who your target audience is. Are you writing it for the GIS crowd detailing technical issues of QGIS development? Or are you more interested in sharing your developed technique with folks interested in bird/nesting research?

Having decided on that, pick up set of clever keywords that define your topic and use Google Scholar or Web of Knowledge to identify journals that have already published something similar on the topic. Keep in mind that your article will be first seen by an editor, and it is her who decide about its future. Good editor takes care of it's audience and would like a piece that fits into the theme of the journal and will interest its readership.

Once you have a list of journals - you could go for the most prestigious one in your domain (that could mean rejection and resubmission to another journal) or lower this criteria and aim at less prestigious journal with hope of getting through the publishing machinery faster.

Last but not least PLOS ONE or cimilar journal could be (relatively fast, open access, but not cheapest) an option. GIS based articles seem to find their [place](http://www.plosone.org/search/simple?searchName=&weekly=&monthly=&startPage=0&filterArticleType=&filterKeyword=&resultView=&query=Geographic%20AND%20information%20AND%20system%2a&x=0&y=0&sort=Relevance&filterStartDate=&filterEndDate=&filterJournals=PLoSONE) in PLOS.

Answer (score 3):

I can't suggest any specific journal, except to say to first look for an [open-access journal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-access_journal) option. If you can, ignore large closed-access publishers. See [*The Cost of Knowledge*](http://thecostofknowledge.com/) for the motivation for why one would do this.

For an extensive directory of open-access journals, see http://www.doaj.org

Another resource is Wikipedia's [List of open-access journals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_open-access_journals)

Answer (score 2):

This is a clear example of QGIS use, and not development of a new tools. Right? So, you must target a journal which describe methodologies. There are generic journals for this in geoscience filed, and I have seen both type of articles (GIS use, and GIS developing) in journals. The top journals on this are:

[Computer & Geosciences](http://www.journals.elsevier.com/computers-and-geosciences/)

[GeoInformatica](http://link.springer.com/journal/10707)

[Environmental Modelling & Software](http://www.journals.elsevier.com/environmental-modelling-and-software/)

All depends on the peer reviewers. So you could first present the paper in a conference, to see what the audience believe. You could also meet editors/peer-reviewers which could advise you choosing a specific journal.